# I get Invalid argument error when try to addRule to stylesheet in ie

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

I am trying to dynamically remove a rule and then add a new one in it's place, to get a calculated animation for a dynamically changing div innerHTML.

```
var ss = document.styleSheets ;           
for(j=0;j<ss[0].cssRules.length;j++)
if(ss[0].cssRules[j].name == "slide")
{  
ss[0].deleteRule(j);                              
break;
}  
ss[0].addRule('@keyframes slide', 'from {top:0px;} to {top:-300px;}', 0);
```

The code above should remove a css animation and insert a new one.
The problem is with the '@' character, if I remove it code passes, but then it's not an animation for ie cause it doesn't have the '@keyframes' identifier. The reason I am going about this in such a manner is because you don't have variables in css for ie11, and you cannot alter stylesheet csstext! So I thought delete the whole rule and insert a new one.
All I'm trying to do is dynamically change this rule:

```
@keyframes slide { 
     from {top:0px;}  
     to   {top:-100px;}
}
```

To this rule for example:

```
@keyframes slide { 
     from {top:0px;}  
     to   {top:-300px;}
}
```

It is really a pain in the neck to try and deal with ie's special world!!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393004/using-javascript-to-dynamically-add-styles-to-stylesheet-but-i-get-a-cannot-rea

Comment: The link you provide is for another question, where user gets null reference error because he is trying to manipulate a non existing rule.My problem is that I cannot add a rule cause of invalid character. Is there a way to push inside the '@' char to the new rule? That's my problem. I found that with ie you can add @media rules because there you have styleSheets[0].media[0] or so, but they don't have for @keyframes!!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've  tested your code and tried to find why it not works in IE. But I could not find a good reason for this. It seems like what you've mentioned that IE could not read the keywork with @. I've just found a workaround for this is to customize a funcition to add the attribute. Here is my working demo.

CSS

```
<style>
    div {
        margin-top: 500px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        position: relative;
        animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes mymove {
        from {
            top: 0px;
        }

        to {
            top: 200px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<script>
    function insertStyleSheetRule(ruleText) {
        let sheets = document.styleSheets;
        if (sheets.length == 0) {
            let style = document.createElement('style');
            style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
            document.head.appendChild(style);
        }
        let sheet = sheets[sheets.length - 1];
        sheet.insertRule(ruleText, sheet.rules ? sheet.rules.length : sheet.cssRules.length);
    }
    insertStyleSheetRule("@keyframes mymove{from {top:0px;} to {top:-300px;}}");
    insertStyleSheetRule("div {margin-top: 500px;width: 100px;height: 100px;background: red;position: relative; animation: mymove 5s infinite;- webkit - animation: mymove 5s infinite;}");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Jenifer, I get a syntax error where it says sheet.insertRule(). IE uses sheet.addRule() syntax. So I changed it to addRule and still I get an invalid argument!

Comment: It seems there is no working around this, so the solution for me was to drop all together the idea of working with IE, I moved to Firefox. I imported GeckoFX to my c# windows forms project, and now I can manipulate all the CSS I want with JS.It was a waste of time to try and figure out IE JS logic.